# Filter values above a threshold

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, openpyxl

I am really new in Python. I get a little confused with when I tried to filter values above a threshold.

For example:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F   G
1  x  x  x  x  x  1000
3  x  x  x  x  x  100000
4  x  x  x  x  x  10
1  x  x  x  x  x  100
4  x  x  x  x  x  1000
5  x  x  x  x  x  1000000
```

Assuming I would wanna filter Column G, for all values of 1000 and above, how do i continue from my current code ? I have already filtered the specific text and date from other columns, but i am unsure on how to filter values above a threshold.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import openpyxl 
from numpy.random import choice

df = pd.read_excel('filepath', sheet_name = 'Sheet1')

df_sample = df.loc[df['Bill Description'].str.contains("Invoice") & df_my['Bill Date'].ge('15/12/2019')]

#to filter values 1000 and above
```

Appreciate if you can show me the code, i have tried a few but they dont work out.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
df[df['G'] >= 1000]
```

Answer (score 0):

Continue your filter if you want to reduce again your dataframe

```
df_sample = df.loc[df['Bill Description'].str.contains("Invoice")
                   & df_my['Bill Date'].ge('15/12/2019')
                   & df[df['G'].ge(1000)]]
```